# Calculate Ra and Rb on a 555 Timer

Tags: resistors, 555

I have all the units and calculations I need but I'm not sure which formula to use, and how to go about it. Please help.

- Frequency - 10.53 Hz
- Duty Cycle - 52.63%
- C2 - 100 uF (e12 value)
- Time High - 49.97 ms
- Time Low - 44.99 ms
- Ra - ?
- Rb - ?

Comment: Hello Jaedon, the relationship between the values of Capacitor C and the Resistors Ra and Rb is very well explained in any of the 555 datasheets you can easily find in the Internet. Please try yourself is quite feasible even with no much knowledge, you already have all the information, frequency and duty cycle. Please try and share the outcome, if have troubles then we will help you

Comment: You seem to be specifying your requirements to 4 significant figures. Realistically, with the 555 and most passive components, you won't do any better than 2 digits -- and are you sure that you can get a 100 uF capacitor with even 1% accuracy?

Comment: There are also quite a few online calculators specifically for computing the cap/resistors for use with a 555. For a couple of examples: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/555-timer-astable-circuit/, https://ohmslawcalculator.com/555-astable-calculator. Since you apparently care about precision, it's probably going to be easier to start with a smaller cap. Most 100 uF caps have tolerances around 20 or 30%. If you use a cap of, say, 1 uF or less, it's going to be much easier to find a tolerance in the 5% (or less) range.